# How to add centered caption to image with text wrapped around it already - html & css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modify a site created long ago by someone else.  The page is nested tables, and I've added images to the right of text (text can wrap if too long) without problems.

I can't figure out how to get a caption centered underneath the image correctly, however.  Everything I've tried, including creating table data cells one for the image and one for the text, winds up really messed up either with the image out in the margin, or the caption beside the photo with the text out in the margin, etc.

The amount of text can vary - and if the lines take up less vertical space than the photo, I'd like it centered on the photo. Right now I'm just using html breaks to try to align it on the photo.  If the text is longer, a few lines may wrap under the photo itself.  But I still need the smaller sized caption to be right under the photo itself.

The caption may be only one line, or can be two lines. The photo sizes also vary.

Here's the code I'm using:

```css
.smallfont {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: NORMAL;
}

.left {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="0" width="700">
  <br>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
      <b class="winners">Text text text text text text text text text.
</b><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>More text here
</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <p>
      <td><img src="name.jpg" width="275" height="168" class="right" border="1">
        <font>
          <br><br>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
          <br>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
          <br>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
          <br>
          <B Class="smallfont">Photo by name</B>
        </font>
        <br><br><br><br></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
      <b class="winners">Text text text text text text text text text.
</b><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>More text here
</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="name.jpg" border="1" width="300" height="212" class="right">
      <font>
        The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy
        dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox
        jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
        The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
        <br>
        <B Class="smallfont">Information about the photo<br>plus other relevant information about the photo</B>
      </font><br><br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd sure appreciate any help with this!!!

UPDATE -- Ok, I got figures to work.  The odd thing is, however, when I use the code snippet function here, it does show the captions in white italic letters, and the caption background black.  But when I actually put it on a webpage, looking at it on a current version of chrome, while it did center the captions, it did NOT make them italics, white, or with a black background.  It was just black text the same size as the rest of the main text.  It also didn't show the light border around the entire thing.

I also couldn't figure out how to center the main text on the image.

Thoughts?

```css
.right {
  margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

figure {
    border: thin #c0c0c0 solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}

figcaption {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font: italic smaller sans-serif;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

.winners {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: #000000; 
    font-size:16px;
        font-weight: 700; 
        text-decoration: normal;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="0" width="700">
<br>

<tr><td bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
<b class="winners">Text text text text text text text text text.
</b><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>More text here
</b></td></tr>
<tr><p><td><figure class="right">
    <img src="topperformers/pjpunjab.jpg" width="275" height="168" border="1">
    <figcaption>Photo information</figcaption>
    </figure>
<font>
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  
<br>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back. 
<br>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
</font>
<br><br><br><br></td></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
<b class="winners">Text text text text text text text text text.
</b><br></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>More text here
</b></td></tr>
<tr><td><figure class="right">
    <img src="topperformers/magicswan.jpg" width="300" height="212" border="1">
    <figcaption>Photo information<br>and other relevant information about the photo</figcaption>
</figure>
<font>
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.
</font><br><br></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use table's for layout... please take a look to flexbox or grid. For your question take a look to [figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

Comment: How large is the site? Are the pages static or dynamic? To be honest that sort of verbose markup with inline styles and loads of misc tags is very hard to maintain over time - bite the bullet and create a cleaner layout using modern methods. for instance, [a modern approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

Comment: The site has about 22 different pages.  It's static.  I'm really not up for redesigning the whole thing - I'm pretty much self taught for both css and html (not terribly well either, I shotgun a lot).  It would take a lot of time and effort to try to get rid of the zillions of nested tables that the guy who created it put in there - and I'd have a steep learning curve myself to do it.  Right now I just need to get darned captions under the photos with the body/main text to the left, if there's some reasonably easy way to do that?  Going to take a look at both of your links now- thanks!

Comment: Sfili_81 and Professor Abronsius, I tried using the figure/figure caption html and css before I posted my question - only I couldn't figure out how to get the main text to the left of the photo & caption when I did that.  The text wound up either above or below the image, rather than to the left of the image... In other words, I could get the caption below the image, but then couldn't get them to align properly with the main text.

Comment: I was finally able to get the figure syntax partially working, and edited my initial question to add the code snippet for that.  In the code snippet it does seem to work properly, but when I actually upload the page and view it on a current version of chrome, it doesn't make the caption text white, or italics, or smaller, or the caption background black.  Nor does it show the border around it all.  I also would like to be able to center the main text on the image if there's a way to do that rather than using breaks and eyeballing it?  Thanks again in advance for help on these issues!